# ExtJs 6.5.2 modern - Remove loadmask message

Tags: javascript, panel, extjs6-modern

I am using a `loadmask` that the `html` property holds all the loading content. The problem that i am facing is that even if `message` property's value is an empty string, `message` allocates space inside the `loadmask` producing something like a dash on the left of my html message.

(Add the code bellow to a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor))

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create({
       xtype: 'panel',
       fullscreen: true,
       html: '<h1>Hello World !!!</h1>',
       listeners: {
           painted: function (panel) {
               panel.mask({
                    xtype: 'loadmask',
                    html: '<div align="center"><h3>Loading Mask</h3>' + 
                    '<p>i am loading...</p></div>',
                    message: '', //empty message holds its opacity
                    indicator: false,
                    style: 'background:#d7ecfd' 
               });
           }
       }
    });
}
});
```

How can i remove or make that space transparent?
Modern Toolkit does not have the `useMsg` property.

I've tried setting the background property (`background: transparent`) at `messageCls` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the sencha devs never thought of a scenario where the message field would go empty.

However you can correct it by adding the below style in the html.

`<style>.x-mask-inner{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important}</style>`

Comment: I would prefer something more "elegant" but it works. Thanks @priyadarshi. Actually they did thought about not showing the message, in classic there is a `useMsg` property.